# Split distinct varchar data from one column into multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I separate the values of the `CallTraversalLog` column into data per row. The result set must not contain any duplicates

```
SeqNum  CallId  DNI     CallTraversalLog
94329   688     29636   CUSTSEG
94329   688     29636   CUSTSEG;PHPM;CARDMNU;CRC;CRCACTIVATION;TPINCHANGE
94332   696     29636   CUSTSEG;PHPM;CARDMNU;CRC;CRCACTIVATION;TPINCHANGE
94333   699     29636   CUSTSEG;PHPM;CARDMNU;CRC;CRCACTIVATION;CRCENROLL
94333   699     29636   CUSTSEG;PHPM;CARDMNU;CRC;CRCACTIVATION;CRCENROLL
94333   702     29636   CUSTSEG;CARDMNU;CRC;CRCBISOA;CRCBI
94334   703     29636   CUSTSEG;PHPM;CARDMNU;CRC;CRCACTIVATION;CRCENROLL
94334   703     29636   CUSTSEG;PHPM;CARDMNU;CRC;CRCACTIVATION;CRCENROLL
94334   706     29636   CUSTSEG;CARDMNU;CRC;CRCBISOA;CRCBI
94336   710     29636   CUSTSEG;PHPM;PBLOGIN;PBMENU
94340   714     29636   CUSTSEG;PHPM;PBLOGIN;PBMENU;PBBI;PBLST3
```

I am lost right now because I don't know how to accomplish this.

The result should be like:

```
Code
CUSTSEG
PHPM
PBLOGIN
PBBI
PBLST3
CARDMNU
CRC
CRCACTIVATION
CRCENROLL
CRCBISOA
CRCBI
TPINCHANGE
```

I tried this solution but I get

> Msg 9411, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   XML parsing: line 1, character 37, semicolon expected

The command I tried is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') data
FROM   
    (SELECT 
        CAST('<M>' + Replace(CallTraversalLog, ';', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data
     FROM   
        tblReportData) AS A
CROSS APPLY 
    Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
```

EDIT: I think I know why I get this error. Some records only contain special character `&`. How can I substitute the special character to make the query work.

Comment: Check this it is working http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6fd60/3

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d8418/2

Comment: I think you have Special characters `& ,
< ,
>,
" ,
' ` in `CallTraversalLog` column

Comment: @artm I need to `EXCLUDE` the records that only contains `CUSTSEG`. How can I do that? I'll update the post.

Comment: @NoDisplayName Some records only contains `CUSTSEG` only in `CallTraversalLog` column, that's why the query doesn't work. SQL complains that it can't split the column data. If those are removed, your solution will work.

Comment: Nope still its working check the second record http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6fd60/3

Comment: @NoDisplayName could you add this at the beginning? `SELECT 'CallTraversalLog' bb UNION ALL SELECT 'CUSTSEG' ` ?

Comment: I didn't get you already it is at beginning only

Comment: @NoDisplayName There are some records with `&`. How can I make this work with those records existing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66183/discussion-between-makalshrek-and-nodisplayname).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few **special character** which cannot be parsed directly by XML.

You need to replace them to escape in node values

```
& - &amp;
< - &lt;
> - &gt;
" - &quot;
' - &#39;

SELECT DISTINCT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') data
FROM   (SELECT Cast('<M>'
                    + Replace(Replace(Replace(CallTraversalLog, ';', ','), '&', '&amp;'), ',', '</M><M>')
                    + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data
        FROM   tblReportData) AS A
       CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the values by running below script:

```
DECLARE @val1 varchar(200) = 'CUSTSEG;PHPM;CARDMNU;CRC;CRCACTIVATION;CRCENROLL'
DECLARE @val2 varchar(20) = null

WHILE LEN(@val1) > 0
BEGIN
    IF PATINDEX('%;%',@val1) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @val2 = SUBSTRING(@val1, 0, PATINDEX('%;%',@val1))
        SELECT @val2

        SET @val1 = SUBSTRING(@val1, LEN(@val2 + ';') + 1, LEN(@val1))
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @val2 = @val1
        SET @val1 = NULL
        SELECT @val2
    END
END
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

use this split func (also deal with one record)

```
 alter  FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString] 
( 
    @string VARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX) 
) 
BEGIN 
IF  CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) IS NULL   --deal with one record
BEGIN
SET @string=@string+@delimiter

    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

        INSERT INTO @output (splitdata)  
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)

    END 
    RETURN 
END
```

and then use this query

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (splt varchar(50))
 DECLARE   cur CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY
FOR SELECT  [CallTraversalLog]
FROM  [dbo].[Sample_Table]   --replace with your table
DECLARE @i varchar(50)
OPEN cur
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @i

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @tbl

SELECT DISTINCT * FROM  [fnSplitString]  ( @i,';') as splt

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @i 
END
CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM @tbl
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've written a test script that cursors through each row and breaks down the delimited segments into a temp `@results` table. It seems a bit convoluted for such a simple task that could be achieved in a few lines in c#/linq. Such is SQL.

Hopefully the code and comments sufficiently explain how it works.

```
-- SETUP TEST ENVIROMENT
declare @csvTest as table
(VAL nvarchar(100))

declare @result as table
(VAL nvarchar(15))

INSERT INTO @csvTest (VAL)
VALUES('CUSTSEG;PHPM;PBLOGIN;PBMENU;PBBI;PBLST3')

INSERT INTO @csvTest (VAL)
VALUES('CUSTSEG;CARDMNU;CRC;CRCBISOA;CRCBI')

INSERT INTO @csvTest (VAL)
VALUES('ONLYONE')

DECLARE @sCsv nvarchar(100)


-- Loop through each row using a cursor
DECLARE CSV_CURSOR cursor FOR 
select VAL
from @csvTest

OPEN CSV_CURSOR

FETCH NEXT FROM CSV_CURSOR 
INTO @sCsv

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
Begin
    declare @start int
    declare @len int
    Set @start = 0
    DECLARE @segment nvarchar(15)

    while 1=1
    Begin
        set @segment = ''

        -- check if there are any delimiters left
        if CHARINDEX(';', @sCsv) = 0
            Set @segment = @sCsv
        else
            select @segment = SUBSTRING(@sCsv, 0, CHARINDEX(';', @sCsv))

        -- insert the segment if not already inserted
        insert into @result (VAL)
        select @segment
        where not exists (select * from @result where VAL = @segment)
        and @segment != ''

        -- break if last
        if CHARINDEX(';', @sCsv) = 0
            break

        -- cut out the segment and continue
        Set @sCsv = SUBSTRING(@sCsv, @start + len(@segment) + 2, LEN(@sCsv) - len(@segment) - 1)
    End

    -- get next row
    FETCH NEXT FROM CSV_CURSOR 
    INTO @sCsv
End

CLOSE CSV_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE CSV_CURSOR

select * from @result
```

Answer (score 0):

Query can be achieved by replacing '&' with some keyword in the inner query and back to original in the outer query.

I hope this work.

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/82d2c/5